# How to configure Yarp routes based on attribute routing

Tags: attributerouting, ms-yarp

i want to user a reverse proxy for a project im working and i have decided to try yarp.
Most if not all documentation on it uses catch-all on and that got me thinking how would i setup something like

/yarp-gateway/api/users, /yarp-gateway/api/users/{id} pointing to /users-api
and then

/yarp-gateway/api/users/{id}/products, /yarp-gateway/api/users/{id}/products/{id2} pointing to /products-api

im sure this can be achieved in code and that's not an issue for me but can this be achieved declaratively via configuration?